# Как один div центрировать по родителю, а второй сместить справа?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Возникла проблема. Такая вот табличка CTA. Надпись "не можете определиться..." нужно центрировать, а кнопку сместить вправо, и чтобы при растягивании страницы все оставалось на местах: один div по центру, второй - на пропорциональном расстоянии справа. Пробовал и флексы и бутстрап. Чувствую, что решение гениально простое, но в голову ничего не приходит. Спасибо

[image: Таблица]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример на **bootstrap 4**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-6 text-center">Loren ipsum Loren ipsum</div>
  <div class="col-3 text-center">button</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Или

```
  <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-6 text-center">Loren ipsum Loren ipsum</div>
  <div class="col-3 text-right">button</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Надпись "не можете определиться..." нужно центрировать, а кнопку
>   сместить вправо, и чтобы при растягивании страницы все оставалось на
>   местах: один div по центру, второй - на пропорциональном расстоянии
>   справа.

Вот так у вас всегда будет текст по центру, а кнопка справа от текста на расстоянии, которое вы укажите (см. в комментариях к коду), и независимо от количества слов:

```css
footer {
  z-index: 1;  /*необязательно*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;  /*необязательно*/
  margin: 10px 0;  /*необязательно*/
  background: url('https://verjul.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/for_slide_2.jpg') center bottom no-repeat;  /*необязательно*/
  background-size: cover;  /*необязательно*/
}

i:after {  /* это для красоты */
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 90, 0.9);
}

footer div {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

footer span {
  z-index: 1;  /*необязательно*/
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

footer button {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  left: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;  /*задать нужный вам отступ кнопки от текста*/
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <i></i>
  <div><span>Не можете определиться? Мы поможем вам!</span><button>Перезвоните мне</button></div>
</footer>
<footer>
  <i></i>
  <div><span>Не можете?</span><button>Перезвоните мне</button></div>
</footer>
<footer>
  <i></i>
  <div><span>Не можете определиться? Мы поможем вам! Не можете определиться? Мы поможем вам!</span><button>Перезвоните мне</button></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/727981

Answer (score 1):

Eсли вложенным блокам задать фиксированную ширину то можно сделать так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}

.child-center {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50px); /* где 50px = width/2*/
}

.child-right {
  background-color: burlywood;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-center"></div>
  <div class="child-right"></div>
</div>
```